# Why dont't I get the intellisense suggestions for the pages in my project after setting up the local XML namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xml-namespaces, tabbedpage

I trying to create a an application similar to Instagram and for That i need to use tabbed pages. the problem is when i want to add different pages to my tabbed page using the local XML namespace I get this error  " the type "local" was not found. are you missing an assembly reference and are all the assemblies have been built?".

I have already added the local xml namespace to the xaml code of my tabbed page like this `"xmlns:local="cls-namespace:InstagramApp">"` .

i searched Google and only found this topic somewhat relevant https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22762/local-xaml-namespace-in-shared-project but it doesn't solve my problem.

I also Searched stackoverflow and couldn't find any relevant topic.

here is the xmal for the tabbed page that I am using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="InstagramApp.TabbedPage1"
            xmlns:local="cls-namespace:InstagramApp">

    <local: Profile />
</TabbedPage>
```

what i want is to get the intellisense suggestion when i type `<local: Profile>` , Profile is the page i want to add to my tabbed page.
Sorry if my terminology isn't correct as  it should be. I am new to programming.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in the xaml namespace declaration. i have used  `xmlns:local="cls-namespace:InstagramApp">` instead of  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InstagramApp">`.

I have used an s instead of r in clr.